# Get Devexpress BootstrapGrid Selected Rows ServerSide

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, devexpress, bootstrap-4

I use devexpress bootstrap grid view, and to get the selected items (since i add checkbox column to the grid to select rows) i use client side event on selected changed.

Now i have an issue, sometimes when user select rows, and try to get selected rows, selected rows array appears as empty array, while it has data.

Can we get these selected rows from sever side?
On clients side, does we can you other than the Grid selected event?

```
<dx:BootstrapGridView ID="dgvData" runat="server" KeyFieldName="Id" Width="100%" 
    ClientInstanceName="dgvData" ClientSideEvents-SelectionChanged="OnDataGridSelectionChanged"
    OnDataBinding="dgvData_DataBinding" EnableRowsCache="false">
    <SettingsAdaptivity AdaptivityMode="HideDataCells" AllowOnlyOneAdaptiveDetailExpanded="true" />
    <SettingsSearchPanel Visible="false" ShowApplyButton="true" />
    <Settings ShowGroupPanel="false" ShowHeaderFilterButton="true" ShowFilterRow="true" />
    <Columns>
        <dx:BootstrapGridViewCommandColumn ShowSelectCheckbox="True" SelectAllCheckboxMode="AllPages" />
        ...
    </Columns>
    <SettingsPager PageSize="1000" PageSizeItemSettings-Visible="false" Visible="false"></SettingsPager>
    <SettingsBootstrap Striped="true" />
</dx:BootstrapGridView>

<script type="text/javascript">
function OnDataGridSelectionChanged() {
    dgvData.GetSelectedFieldValues('Id', OnDataGridSelectionComplete);
}

var DataKeys = [];
function OnDataGridSelectionComplete(values) {
    DataKeys = values;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you already tried using `GetRowValues` method with `dgvData.KeyFieldName` as its parameter? `BootstrapGridView` has many similar behaviors to `ASPxGridView`, so you can use same approach from the latter to the former.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go through documentation: [Bootstrap GridView - Selection](https://demos.devexpress.com/bootstrap/GridView/Selection.aspx#Selection)

Try setting client-side events for getting selection as below:

```
<ClientSideEvents Init="onSelectionGridViewAction" SelectionChanged="onSelectionGridViewAction" EndCallback="onSelectionGridViewAction" />
```

//js

```
function onSelectionGridViewAction(s, e) {
    $("#selectionLabel").html("Total rows selected: " + s.GetSelectedRowCount());
}
```

**Refer:** [BootstrapGridView - How to retrieve values from a Bootstrap GridView in code-behind](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T561411/bootstrapgridview-how-to-retrieve-values-from-a-bootstrap-gridview-in-code-behind)

> To get BootstrapGridView row values on the server side, you can use
>   the [GetRowValues](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.GetRowValues.method) method. See the [GetRowValues](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.GetRowValues.method) article, which
>   contains a sample project illustrating how to use this method.
>   Although this article targets ASPxGridView, the same solution is
>   actual for BootstrapGridView as well.